# Widget drag and drop issues in custom layout plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I am planning to submit a CKeditor plugin that adds bootstrap layouts.However i have found several bugs that in my opinion are result of CKEditor's default behaviour. I have tried to fix them but without success.

The main bugs are:

1.When a layout with more than 1 column is inserted, a widget out of the layout can only be dragged and dropped into the first column.

2.When there are is 3-column layout. Because of the bug pointed in '2' the widget can only be dragged into the first column.Then the widget can easily be dragged into the middle column but cannot be dragged to the third, even if it was in the middle beforehand.

The plugin can be found here : https://github.com/radko26/CKEditor_layoutmanagerPlugin/tree/master/layoutmanager

Please give me some tips, i am looking forward to your comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug or rather a "lack of feature" in the lineutils plugin used by the widgets system to implement drag and drop. You can report it on http://dev.ckeditor.com

BTW. Accidentally, just a few minutes ago I wrote an answer regarding editing layouts in CKEditor https://stackoverflow.com/a/29555872/1464696.