# CKEditor Turn Off Advanced Content Filter

Tags: ckeditor

I'm having difficulty deactivating the Advanced Content Filter (config.allowedContent = true; dosen't seem to work). I've tried everything that I've read on the forums, including clearing the cache, and making it an external file.

[CKEditor 4.2.2 - allowedContent = true is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967092/ckeditor-4-2-2-allowedcontent-true-is-not-working)

I've even added config.protectedSource.push lines, and they work to a point. The CKEditor still adds div tags and partially deletes other tags.

I'm creating a set of well designed templates for clients to use, so In the end I don't want CKEditor to touch my code at all. Here is what I have in the config.js.  If anyone can see something I did wrong, or knows of a way to make it work, please help this somewhat stressed web guy.

Thanks,
Rusty

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.toolbarGroups = [
{ name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
{ name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
{ name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
{ name: 'insert' },
{ name: 'links' },
{ name: 'others' },
'/',
{ name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
{ name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
{ name: 'styles' },
{ name: 'colors' },
{ name: 'tools' },
{ name: 'about' }
];

// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
// misc options
config.allowedContent = true; // allowedContent doesn't work :-(
// Protected Source
config.protectedSource.push(/<section>[\s\S]*?<\/section>/gi); // allow <section></section>
config.protectedSource.push(/<span>[\s\S]*?<\/span>/gi); // allow <span></span>
config.protectedSource.push( /<link[\s\S]*?\>/g ); // allow <link> tag
config.protectedSource.push( /<!--[\s\S]*?\>/g ); // allow <comment> tag
config.protectedSource.push( /<br[\s\S]*?\/>/g );   // allow BR Tags
config.protectedSource.push(/<script>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi); // allow <script></script>
config.protectedSource.push(/<div>[\s\S]*?<\/div>/gi); // allow <div></div>

config.removeButtons = 'Anchor,Iframe';
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6'; // format button options
config.height = '500px'; // edit window height
config.skin = 'moono';
config.stylesSet = 'vam_styles:/templates/admin/-css/vam_styles.js'; // style button options
// Only add rules for p and span elements.
config.stylesheetParser_validSelectors = /\^(p|span\div)\.\w+/;
config.stylesheetParser_skipSelectors
```

};

Comment: The ckEditor version I'm using is ckEditor 4.4.7

Answer (score 0):

> I'm creating a set of well designed templates for clients to use, so In the end I don't want CKEditor to touch my code at all.

This is not possible. CKEditor is not a web site builder into which you can load any possible HTML. It is a rich **text** editor. So you should use it to edit the textual part of the website, not the whole layout.

For instance, if you had a layout with two columns and some header above them, it would be best if there were 3 editors - one for each column and one for the header. Of course, in this basic case CKEditor could be used to edit or 3 sections at once, but **the more complex the layout the more important it is to use CKEditor correctly**.

PS. It's CKEditor, not ckEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I wasn't talking about site design templates, but page design templates. On the Full featured version of CKEditor there is a template button that we've been able to enhance. We now are able to let our clients choose several well designed  page layouts that are responsive for different devises. It is very effective.

After trying everything I found the culprit that was causing the problem. I was using `<br>` instead of `<br /`>. As soon as I switched the editor left my code alone.

Best Wishes!
Rusty